# Firebase realtime database once method doesn't work in web extensions

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, tampermonkey

i'm using Firebase API to anonymously login and get data from Tampermonkey extension. Works as charm in Chrome but doesn't work in Firefox at all.

```
firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function(error) {
    console.log("login error: "+ error);
});

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    firebase.database().ref().once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
        debugger; // never gets here
        GM_setValue("lastUpdate", new Date());
        GM_setValue("lastState", snapshot.val());
    }).catch(function(error) {
        debugger; // never gets here
        console.log("error reading DB: " + error);
    });
  }
});
```

it never comes to debugger in Firefox. No errors in console at all. what could be a reason? GM_xmlhttprequest instead works more or less in both, but i need auth as well so wanted to use official API.

thank you

UPDATE: after recent Chrome update it doesn't work there as well. Silently dies somewhere...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns that there is a value in localStorage that preventing everything from working. code below at application init solves issue.

```
if (localStorage) { // fix for API
    localStorage.removeItem("firebase:previous_websocket_failure");
}
```

something sets it to true and nobody is cleaning it. there are issues about it since 2017 on github about this, seems not resolved yet.