# Cannot force Firebase Realtime Database to use websockets only - Long polling blocked by CSP

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I am busy creating a Google chrome extension, and under the new rules of manifest V.3, you are no longer allowed to run any remote script and this gets blocked by the Content Security Policy (CSP).

Firebase Realtime Database has two ways of communicating. Websockets being the primary, and long polling being the fallback or secondary.

The way it usually works is that if a Websockets connection fails, it reverts to long-polling, if long polling is successful it goes back to Websockets. But if your CSP is blocking the long poll, I am then stuck and the app can never connect again.

```
Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.

2.b786d402.chunk.js:2 Refused to load the script 'https://xxxx-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app/.lp?start=t&ser=75721928&cb=1&v=5&p=1:592645519845:web:db72abd212b7364c72170c&ns=tonews-default-rtdb' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

I can revert this by removing the extension and re-installing it.

I have found some posts online, where its mentioned I could just change my configuration.

The solution recommends just changing 'databaseURL' field in the firebase config to start with wss:// instead of https://...

This works, for about a week or so, but thereafter I get stuck in CSP prison again..or does it? Hard to tell since reinstalling the extension solves the problem anyway, and is required to apply the new changes..

```
"firebase": "^9.6.1",
```

```
  "name": "xxxx",
  "description": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open the popup"
  },
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "index.html"
  },
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'",
      "sandbox": "sandbox allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'https://apis.google.com/' 'https://www.gstatic.com/' 'https://*.firebaseio.com' 'https://*.firebasedatabase.app' 'https://www.googleapis.com' 'https://ajax.googleapis.com'; object-src 'self'"

  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "favicon-16x16.png",
    "48": "favicon-32x32.png",
    "128": "android-chrome-192x192.png"
  }

}
```

I'm honestly stuck and very frustrated because even if I do find a fix, it's hard to verify it..

Comment: When that happens, you have to clear the `localStorage`: there will be an item there `firebase:previous_websocket_failure` set to `true` that prevents going back to websocket.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko I have noticed this too and added localStorage.removeItem("Firebase:previous_websocket_failure") to the useEffect within App.tsx 
Do you think this is a reasonable solution?

Comment: The reasonable solution would be that the Firebase team solved the bug that causes it, [which seems to have been running for quite a while now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61823148/3930351). In the meantime, if it works, it works :)